# Is there any chance of change style of facebook send button

Tags: html, facebook, css

Is possible change style of facebook send button ?

```
.pluginButton {
   height: 32px !important;
   line-height: 32px !important;
}
```

Comment: Besides the options the generator offers, resp. the documentation mentions - No. No _allowed_ ones anyway. Facebook does not want you to change the look&feel of their social plugins beyond that. And that has to do not only with brand recognition, but also with preventing users from fraud.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably need more informations to understand what you are trying to achieve but yeah, if you are dealing with a plugin you should be able to do so by adding more specificity to your selector for example:

```
.fb-some-container > .something-else > .pluginButton {
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   -moz-appearance:    none;
   appearance:         none;
   height: 32px;
   line-height: 32px;
}
```

Doing this you might be able to avoid using `!important`

Hope this helped :)

Comment: i am trying to change style of button but it is not working

Comment: mhhh have yout tryed with appearance?

Comment: I'll add that to my answer

Answer (score 0):

Changing the appearance of social plugins is not allowed and not possible, they get loaded in an iframe. use your own button with the `FB.ui` send function of the JS SDK instead.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog